# Only interface method is typed

Tags: java

I have this interface

```
/**
 * Exports data provided by a {@link IDataProvider} as described by {@link IExportableColumn}s. This interface is used by
 * {@link ExportToolbar} to provide the export functionality.
 *
 * @author Jesse Long
 * @see ExportToolbar
 * @see IExportableColumn
 */
public interface IDataExporter
    extends IClusterable
{
    ...
    /**
     * Exports the data provided by the {@link IDataProvider} to the {@link OutputStream}.
     *
     * @param <T>
     *      The type of each row of data provided by the {@link IDataProvider}.
     * @param dataProvider
     *      The {@link IDataProvider} from which to retrieve the data.
     * @param columns
     *      The {@link IExportableColumn} to use to describe the data.
     * @param outputStream
     *      The {@link OutputStream} to which to write the exported data.
     * @throws IOException If an error occurs.
     */
    <T> void exportData(IDataProvider<T> dataProvider, List<IExportableColumn<T, ?, ?>> columns, OutputStream outputStream)
        throws IOException;
}
```

Is there somehow in the class that implements this interface i can type T to something specific, i want to make sure that T implements another interface?

Comment: `<T extends Whatever> void exportData(...)`?

Comment: Seems to be a lot of hatred for 'I' in front of interface names but I find it easier to pick out it is an interface quickly, I know you can decorate classes with their types in eclipse putting a little symbol against them but still Its not an awful convention (albeit borrowed from C#)

Comment: @reevesy: Java people love to trash C people ... mostly it's a friendly, competitive, colleagial thing, but for others, well ... human nature is what it is.

Comment: When you see a type, why do you care that it's an interface or class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always want to force `T` to implement some interface, just use

```
<T extends Thing> void exportData(. . .)
```

If you want to restrict `T` only in the implementing class, you can make the entire interface generic (instead of just the method). This may be a good idea anyway:

```
/**
 * Exports data provided by a {@link IDataProvider} as described by {@link IExportableColumn}s. This interface is used by
 * {@link ExportToolbar} to provide the export functionality.
 * @param <T>
 *      The type of each row of data provided by the {@link IDataProvider}.
 *
 * @author Jesse Long
 * @see ExportToolbar
 * @see IExportableColumn
 */

public interface<T> IDataExporter extends IClusterable
{
    ...
    /**
     * Exports the data provided by the {@link IDataProvider} to the {@link OutputStream}.
     *
     * @param dataProvider
     *      The {@link IDataProvider} from which to retrieve the data.
     * @param columns
     *      The {@link IExportableColumn} to use to describe the data.
     * @param outputStream
     *      The {@link OutputStream} to which to write the exported data.
     * @throws IOException If an error occurs.
     */
    void exportData(IDataProvider<T> dataProvider, List<IExportableColumn<T, ?, ?>> columns, OutputStream outputStream)
        throws IOException;
}
```

Then you can bind `T` in the implementing class declaration:

```
public class MyClass implements IDataExporter<MyRowType> { . . . }
```

Comment: org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.repeater.data.table.export The interface is from a package so i can't change it without copying a lot of code.

Answer (score 2):

```
<T extends MyRequisiteType> void exportData(IDataProvider<T> dataProvider, List<IExportableColumn<T,?,?>> columns, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException;
```

Why the 2 unbounded type parameters in `IExportableColumn<T,?,?>`?  When I see this in application code I always have the sense I'm missing something.

You can also make the whole interface parametric, but from what I'm seeing the number of parameters would need to be pretty big.  3 at the very least.